# TestNG How to execute beforeclass() method on testfailure

Tags: java, testng

I have login steps in `beforeclass()` and after that tests starts executing. If there is a test failure, `beforeclass()` method should be reinvoked. I'm using test listener class.

```java
public class LoginTests {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.print("login in application");        
    }    
      
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
            
    }     
      
    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
      
    }     
      
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.print("go to first page");               
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.print("go to second page");          
    }
          
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {       
        //if there is test failure run  beforeclass() method          
    }
      
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried and mention the problem that you are facing as part of the question.

Comment: By "reinvoking the beforeClass" are you saying that, you need to logout? In that case, you could try `@AfterClass`?

Comment: I updated post with sample code, so what I need to do is that if i.e test1 will failed execute beforeclass() method before test2 will execute

Comment: Does `beforeClass` update any variables in your test class which are to be used in the test methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could know the result of the test in `@AfterMethod`, so if it is failed, then you could repeat the logic in the after method. No need for test listener in this case.

```java
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() throws Exception {
     //login
 }

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestContext tc, ITestResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        return;
    }

    // login
}
```

Comment: i tried it  before but it does not worked for me, I'm using page object model

Comment: ohh, I need 15 reputation :/ to upvote  sorry